# Short but though SQL Query (T-SQL,SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have 2 tables, each tables has N columns. There are NO duplicate rows in `table1`

And now we want to know what datasets in `table2` (including duplicates) are also contained in `table1`.

I tried

```
select * from table1
intersect
select * from table2
```

But this only gives me unique rows that are in both tables. But I don't want unique rows, are want to see all rows in table2 that are in `table1`...

Keep in mind!! I cannot do

```
select *
from table1 a, table b
where a.table1col = b.table2col
```

...because I don't know the number of columns of the tables at runtime.

Sure I could do something with dynamic SQL and iterate over the column numbers but I'm asking this precisely because it seems too simple a query for that kind of stuff..

Example:

```
create table table1 (table1col int)
create table table2 (table2col int)

insert into table1 values (8)
insert into table1 values (7)

insert into table2 values (1)
insert into table2 values (8)
insert into table2 values (7)
insert into table2 values (7)
insert into table2 values (2)
insert into table2 values (9)
```

I want my query then to return:

```
8
7
7
```

Comment: In your example, what do you gain by knowing there are **two** `7` rows in `table2`? Are you going to do some operation that affects one but not the other?

Comment: Actually, I'm doing a very ambitious project. I have a huuuge database without ForeignKey relationships, and through comparing each column in the database with each other column in the database, my program will try to document/create the relationships. Somewhere in that process I need this stuff I'm asking here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the amount of columns is not know, you will have to resort to a value computed over a row to make a match.

One such function is `CHECKSUM`.

> Returns the checksum value computed over a row of a table, or over a
>   list of expressions. CHECKSUM is intended for use in building hash
>   indices.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  tm.*
FROM    (
          SELECT  CS = CHECKSUM(*)
          FROM    Table2
        ) tm          
        INNER JOIN (          
          SELECT  CS = CHECKSUM(*)
          FROM    Table2          
          INTERSECT
          SELECT  CHECKSUM(*)          
          FROM    Table1
        ) ti ON ti.CS = tm.CS
```

Note that `CHECKSUM` might introduce collisions. You will have to test for that before doing any operation on your data.

**Edit**

In case you are using `SQL Server 2005`, you might make this a bit more robust by throwing in `HASH_BYTES`.

The downside of `HASH_BYTES`is that you need to specify the columns on which you want to operate but for all the columns you do known up-front, you could use this to prevent collisions.

Comment: great answer does exactly what I need, very elegant and intuitiv too understand code to. I just need to count the result of your query, so I don't know exactly what you mean with collisions and don't need to know i guess, but maybe you can elaborate on that. I use sql server 2008 R2 as a novice actually..

Comment: @cdbeelala89 - It is **possible** for two distinct rows to compute to the **same** checksum. You will have to verify if that is the case and device a new strategy if it is.

Answer (score 0):

EXCEPT vs INTERSECT - [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)

EXCEPT returns any distinct values from the left query that are not also found on the right query.

INTERSECT returns any distinct values that are returned by both the query on the left and right sides of the INTERSECT operand.

Maybe EXCEPT can solve your problem

Comment: sorry - you do want to duplicate rows to come through.

Comment: Hm, BTW, I thought until now that EXCEPT just substracts one query result from another. Didn't read about the distinct part... Seems like I need a NON-distinct EXCEPT too then, because EXCEPT is in my code, but due too insuffient testing so far, I did not notice...